# How to preserve the state after press of refresh button in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, quasar

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0R3p.png) [image: feedback page]

I have 2 different page, one is login, and the other is giving feedback once the user has logged in. when i am in feedback page, if the user presses refresh button, it is going back to login page. I want it to be in the same feedback page once the user presses refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save state to [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

1. If user navigates to the feedback page -> save the flag to the `localStorage`
2. At the app start, you should check is flag exists and redirect a user to the feedback page.
3. Remove flat when user submits feedback (prevent further redirects)